# Disabling selected ligatures with microtype

Tags: microtype, ligatures

With a font in `T1` encoding, using `pdfTeX` and the package `microtype`, I'd like to disable the ligatures for "ff" and "ffi", but keep the ligature for "fi". If I type in the preamble

```
\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding=T1}
```

`microtype` will disable all the ligatures above. How could I keep the ligature for "fi"? I have tried

```
\DisableLigatures[ff]{encoding=T1}
```

and

```
\DisableLigatures[f_f]{encoding=T1}
```

but none works (as expected, though).

Comment: I have a Type 1 face which works fine with the ligature "fi" but does not have the right glyphs for "ffi" or "ff". I could try with workarounds such as described in The TeXBook, but I'd rather proceed by disabling them explicitly, if possible.

Comment: You can disable only the "triple" ligatures ffl + ffi by using `\char"1B` in the declaration. But you can't differentiate between fl and fi. If you want to fine tune ligatures you will have to change the tfm files. Did you contacted the authors of fourier(x) regarding your other problem?

Answer (score 7):

You can disable only the "triple" ligatures ffl + ffi by using `\char"1B` in the declaration. But you can't differentiate between fl and fi. If you want to fine tune ligatures you will have to change the `tfm` files. Did you contact the authors of fourier(x) regarding your other problem?

Comment: Thanks for keeping this in mind. I have tried `\DisableLigatures[\char"1B]{encoding=T1}`, I have also tried with the value `"1B`, and even with `char"1B`, but none have worked. Did it work for you? Regarding the text figures issue, I am considering contacting the authors, but maybe it would be good to know if there is someone else who has tried and whether he or she found the same problem or not.