# How do ligatures work?

Tags: tex-core, ligatures

The TeXbook doesn't explain ligatures more than presenting the existing ones, the same for TeX By Topic. So, how are they defined? Is there a third way besides active characters and control sequences to ask TeX to do something unusual? Can we create new ones?

Comment: see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106345/which-ligatures-do-the-fonts-used-in-my-document-offer/106446#106446

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ligatures are defined in either the .tfm or .vf: http://tug.org/tugboat/tb11-1/tb27knut.pdf

or in the font itself if using a non-TeX (.tfm or .vf) font using a TeX-variant such as XeTeX or LuaTeX.